# CRUD in Angular 11: how to solve these two problems with the delete and update buttons

Tags: angular

I created a crud project in Angular; the execution does not give me any errors, only that I am having problems with both the Delete button and the Update button. I explain in detail what happens.

When I click on the **Delete button**, the student is deleted but to make sure that it is no longer visible on the table I have to update the web page. I want that when I delete a student, then it returns me to the table without that student I deleted without updating the web page.
As I'm a beginner, why doesn't this work?

While when I click on the **Update button**, the window regarding the details of the relevant student does not open for me. I want that when I click on this button a window opens with the student's details as in the picture. The code seems correct to me, maybe I forgot something? Why am I having this problem?

[Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xj6C9.png)

One thing I noticed now considering the web console, when I click on the Udate button I get this tip:
*It looks like you're using ngModel on the same form field as formControlName.
Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and will be removed in a future version of Angular.*

student.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';  
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';  
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';  
  
@Injectable({  
  providedIn: 'root'  
})  
  
export class StudentService {  
  
  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/';  
  
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }  
  
  getStudentList(): Observable<any> {  
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`+'students-list');  
  }  
  
  createStudent(student: object): Observable<object> {  
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}`+'save-student', student);  
  }  
  
  deleteStudent(id: number): Observable<any> {  
    return this.http.delete(`${this.baseUrl}/delete-student/${id}`, { responseType: 'text' });  
  }  
  
  getStudent(id: number): Observable<Object> {  
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/student/${id}`);  
  }  
  
  updateStudent(id: number, value: any): Observable<Object> {  
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/update-student/${id}`, value);  
  }  
    
}
```

student-list.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';  
import { StudentService } from '../student.service';  
import { Student } from '../student';  
import { Observable,Subject } from "rxjs";  
  
import {FormControl,FormGroup,Validators} from '@angular/forms';  
  
@Component({  
  selector: 'app-student-list',  
  templateUrl: './student-list.component.html',  
  styleUrls: ['./student-list.component.css']  
})  
export class StudentListComponent implements OnInit {  
  
 constructor(private studentservice:StudentService) { }  
  
  studentsArray: any[] = [];  
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};  
  dtTrigger: Subject<any>= new Subject();  
  
  students: Observable<Student[]>;  
  student : Student=new Student();  
  deleteMessage=false;  
  studentlist:any;  
  isupdated = false;      
   
  
  ngOnInit() {  
    this.isupdated=false;  
    this.dtOptions = {  
      pageLength: 6,  
      stateSave:true,  
      lengthMenu:[[6, 16, 20, -1], [6, 16, 20, "All"]],  
      processing: true  
    };     
    this.studentservice.getStudentList().subscribe(data =>{  
    this.students =data;  
    this.dtTrigger.next();  
    })  
  }  
    
  deleteStudent(id: number) {  
    this.studentservice.deleteStudent(id)  
      .subscribe(  
        data => {  
          console.log(data);  
          this.deleteMessage=true;  
          this.studentservice.getStudentList().subscribe(data =>{  
            this.students =data  
            })  
        },  
        error => console.log(error));  
  }  
  
  updateStudent(id: number){  
    this.studentservice.getStudent(id)  
      .subscribe(  
        data => {  
          this.studentlist=data             
        },  
        error => console.log(error));  
  }  
  
  studentupdateform=new FormGroup({  
    student_id:new FormControl(),  
    student_name:new FormControl(),  
    student_email:new FormControl(),  
    student_branch:new FormControl()  
  });  
  
  updateStu(updstu){  
    this.student=new Student();   
   this.student.student_id=this.StudentId.value;  
   this.student.student_name=this.StudentName.value;  
   this.student.student_email=this.StudentEmail.value;  
   this.student.student_branch=this.StudentBranch.value;  
   console.log(this.StudentBranch.value);  
     
  
   this.studentservice.updateStudent(this.student.student_id,this.student).subscribe(  
    data => {       
      this.isupdated=true;  
      this.studentservice.getStudentList().subscribe(data =>{  
        this.students =data  
        })  
    },  
    error => console.log(error));  
  }  
  
  get StudentName(){  
    return this.studentupdateform.get('student_name');  
  }  
  
  get StudentEmail(){  
    return this.studentupdateform.get('student_email');  
  }  
  
  get StudentBranch(){  
    return this.studentupdateform.get('student_branch');  
  }  
  
  get StudentId(){  
    return this.studentupdateform.get('student_id');  
  }  
  
  changeisUpdate(){  
    this.isupdated=false;  
  }  
}
```

student-list.component.html file

```js
<div class="panel panel-default">  
  <div class="panel-heading">  
      <h1 style="text-align: center">Students</h1><br>  
      <div class="row" [hidden]="!deleteMessage">  
             
                <div class="col-sm-4"></div>  
                <div class="col-sm-4">  
                        <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible">  
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>  
                                <strong>Student Data Deleted</strong>  
                        </div>  
                </div>  
                <div class="col-sm-4"></div>  
        </div>             
    </div>  
  
    
  <div class="panel-body">  
      <table  class="table table-hover table-sm" datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions"  
      [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger"  >  
          <thead class="thead-light">  
              <tr>  
                  <th>Student Name</th>  
                  <th>Student Email</th>  
                  <th>Student Branch</th>  
                  <th>Action</th>  
                    
              </tr>  
          </thead>  
          <tbody>  
               <tr *ngFor="let student of students | async "> 
                  <td>{{student.student_name}}</td>  
                  <td>{{student.student_email}}</td>  
                  <td>{{student.student_branch}}</td>  
                  <td><button (click)="deleteStudent(student.student_id)" class='btn btn-primary'><i class="fa fa-futboll-0">Delete</i></button>   
                    <button (click)="updateStudent(student.student_id)" class='btn btn-info'  
                    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Update</button>  
                  </td>  
                </tr>   
          </tbody><br>  
      </table>  
  </div>  
</div>   
  
<div class="modal" id="myModal">  
        <div class="modal-dialog">  
          <div class="modal-content">  
                <form [formGroup]="studentupdateform" #updstu (ngSubmit)="updateStu(updstu)">  
            <!-- Modal Header -->  
            <div class="modal-header">  
              <h4 class="modal-title" style="text-align: center">Update Student</h4>  
                
            </div>  
              
            <!-- Modal body -->  
            <div class="modal-body" *ngFor="let student of studentlist " >  
                <div [hidden]="isupdated">  
  
                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control"  formControlName="student_id" [(ngModel)]="student.student_id">  
                            <div class="form-group">  
                                <label for="name">Student Name</label>  
                                <input type="text" class="form-control"  formControlName="student_name" [(ngModel)]="student.student_name"  >  
                            </div>  
                      
                            <div class="form-group">  
                                <label for="name">Student Email</label>  
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="student_email" [(ngModel)]="student.student_email">  
                            </div>  
                      
                            <div class="form-group">  
                                <label for="name">Student Branch</label>  
                                  <select class="form-control" formControlName="student_branch" required>                                     
                                    <option value="B-Tech" [selected]="'B-Tech' == student.student_branch">B-Tech</option>  
                                    <option value="BCA" [selected]="'BCA' == student.student_branch">BCA</option>  
                                    <option value="MCA" [selected]="'MCA' == student.student_branch" >MCA</option>  
                                    <option value="M-Tech" [selected]="'M-Tech' == student.student_branch">M-Tech</option>  
                                  </select>                                 
                            </div>                     
                  </div>    
                  <div [hidden]="!isupdated">  
                      <h4>Student Detail Updated!</h4>  
                  </div>          
                      
            </div>  
              
            <!-- Modal footer -->  
            <div class="modal-footer" >  
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [hidden]="isupdated">Update</button>  
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="changeisUpdate()">Close</button>  
            </div>  
              
        </form>  
          </div>  
        </div>  
      </div>
```

Comment: to get the list to refresh after deleting, try putting `this.dtTrigger.next(); ` in the `deleteStudent()` method after `this.students =data`

Comment: I would suggest splitting this question into two separate questions, like: "*Why doesn't list refresh after removing item?*" and "*Why doesn't modal display when button clicked?*"  Then just share the minimum code relevant to each question.  This will make it easier for others to assist you :-)

Comment: @BizzyBob adding this.dtTrigger.next (); I get this message: cannot reinitialize datatable. for more information about this error ...
How is it resolved?

Comment: I notice something strange.  You define students as observable `students: Observable<Student[]>;`, but then you assign students unpacked value from response `this.students = data` which is not observable.  Since this is not being used as observable do this: 1) Correct your type: `students: Student[];` 2) remove the async pipe from the template `<tr *ngFor="let student of students">`. This might fix it without needing to call `dtTrigger.next()`.

Comment: if that does not fix the issue, check out this example from the docs that shows [how to re-render your datatable](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/advanced/rerender)

Comment: I tried but I don't solve anything. Everything like before.. I was thinking of doing a window.location.reload () after the delete. What do you think about it?